# Settings between two projects msvs

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am trying to pass a configuration variable between two projects. In `ConsoleApp1`, I created the settings variable `test2`, and in `WpfApp1` I created a variable for the settings `test1`.

project ConsoleApp1:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args){}
        public static string Test2
        {
            set
            {
                ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings.Default.test2 = value;
                ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to write the variable `test1` from another project, but it is assigned to the project `WpfApp1` although I did not create it

project WpfApp1:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {    
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.test1 = "var1";
            ConsoleApp1.Program.Test2 = "var1";
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

in the user.config file for `WpfApp1` I get

```
<userSettings>
    <WpfApp1.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="test1" serializeAs="String">
            <value>var1</value>
        </setting>
    </WpfApp1.Properties.Settings>
    <ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="test2" serializeAs="String">
            <value>var1</value>
        </setting>
    </ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

Question: tell me what I am wrong or give direction where to look. How to share settings?

Comment: Do you want both applications to have same (shared) settings? Or want to update settings of one application (console) from other application (wpf)?

Comment: @fhnaseer Any one of your options will suit me.

Comment: You can create one settings file and add this file to both applications as a link,

Comment: @fhnaseer Thanks, I also thought about it, but I was going to edit the user.config file for `ConsoleApp1` itself. But maybe there is a solution for the settings tool?

Comment: Just use custom JSON/XML/etc file. Out-of-box settings don't work the way you want.

Comment: It's saving `test1` under `WpfApp1.Properties.Settings` and `test2` under `ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings` config node which is expected. Could you describe more about what is unexpected and what is expected behavior in your point of view?

Comment: @RezaAghaei , I now get the `test2` variable in both the user.config file for `ConsoleApp1` and the user.config for  `WpfApp1` They even have the same `PublicKeyToken`. The only difference is that the files user.config are in different folders. I expected that if I access the code in `ConsoleApp1` then the property will be executed in the namespace `ConsoleApp1`.